# Show subtitles in a MPMoviePlayerViewController by default

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there any way to show subtitules on a movie loaded by MPMoviePlayerViewController by default?? The movie has subs embed in the video.

Thank you!

Comment: If they are embedded in video aren't they displayed? Pls check the encoding to make sure

Comment: Hi, They are embedded in video and display ok but only when you activate them, they doesn't show by default, that is the problem.. Thks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature is missing in the `MPMoviePlayer` playback classes. This is obviously rather annoying, and you should consider filing a feature request with Apple. You can use the `AVPlayer` class instead, which as a `.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled` property: the downside is it's somewhat more complicated to use and only available on iOS 4.0+.