# AVURLAsset load webvtt file

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avurlasset, webvtt

I am trying to use AVURLAsset to load a webvtt file.

Below is my code.

```
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://somewhere/some.vtt";
    NSURL *urlStream = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlAddress];
    AVAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:urlStream options:nil];

    NSArray *requestKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tracks",@"playable",nil];
    [avAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestKeys completionHandler:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

        //complete block here
        AVKeyValueStatus status =[avAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:nil];
        if(status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded) {

            //loaded block !
            //Question 1
            CMTime assetTime = [avAsset duration];
            Float64 duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(assetTime);
            NSLog(@"%f", duration);

            //Question 2
            AVMediaSelectionGroup *subtitle = [avAsset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristicLegible];
            NSLog(@"%@", subtitle);
        }
        else {
            //don’t load block ! 
        }
    });
}];
```

Question 1: It always go into the "Loaded Block", but I find the avAsset's duration is not complete, that means the data is not loaded? How should I modify it?

Question 2: I am trying to use it to my avplayer's subtitle, but the AVMediaSelectionGroup is always null. What should I do?

Comment: Hi is this working, I tried this but its not working ? any idea?

Comment: Did you figure this out? any updates?

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, add `duration` to your keys:

```
NSArray *requestKeys = @[@"tracks",@"playable", @"duration"];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I add it but the result is the same.

Comment: oh no. have you tried opening the URL in Mobile Safari?

Comment: that sounds wrong. do you have a public link to the file?

Comment: Ok - I see, what are you trying to do? Duration works for me, but `AVMediaSelectionGroup` only seems to be available for subtitles inside movies.

Comment: the duration you got is ?

Comment: 3978.03s or 1hr 6minutes and 18seconds

Comment: It should be 6951.053

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a solution over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37945178/171933 Basically you need to use an `AVMutableComposition` to join the video with the subtitles and then play back that composition.

About your second question: `mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic` seems to only be supported when these "characteristics" are already baked into either the media file or your m3u8 stream, according to [this statement by an Apple engineer (bottom of the page)](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16554).