# AVUrlAsset and WebVTTs

Tags: ios, tvos, webvtt

On iOS/TVOS, is it possible to load a remote .vtt file from a URL and use it as a subtitle track with a remote HLS video also loaded from a URL (as opposed to the VTT being specified within the m3u8 playlist)?

pseudocode:

```
AVAsset* video_asset = AVAsset( "http://video.m3u8" );
AVAsset* subtitle_asset = AVAsset( "http://subtitle.vtt" );
AVPlayer player = player.playVideoWithSubtitle( video_asset, subtitle_asset );
player.play().
```

Edit:

The docs mention using AVAsset for subtitles, but does anyone actually have an example? I can only find examples regarding adding strings as subtitles rather than loading a remote VTT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted a solution over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37945178/171933 Basically you need to use an `AVMutableComposition` to join the video with the subtitles and then play back that composition.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/), this is possible

> AVAsset is an abstract class to represent timed audiovisual media such
>   as videos and sounds. Each asset contains a collection of tracks that
>   are intended to be presented or processed together, each of a uniform
>   media type, including but not limited to audio, video, text, closed
>   captions, and **subtitles**.

You should use `AVMutableComposition` to combine assets then. You would combine asset with the video with an asset with subtitles. Docs:

> You can insert AVAsset objects into an AVMutableComposition object in
>   order to assemble audiovisual constructs from one or more source
>   assets.

Comment: Can you provide an example?